# Have trouble implementing dynamic checklist on react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am just started on react and I have a challenge with implementing dynamic checkboxes. I have the checkbox items in a firestore collection and fetch them as an array which I store into something that looks like this:

```
        const checkboxes = [
        {
          name: 'check-box-1',
          key: 'checkBox1',
          label: 'Check Box 1',
          id: 'first',
          value: false
        },
        {
          name: 'check-box-2',
          key: 'checkBox2',
          label: 'Check Box 2',
          id: 'second',
          value: true
        },
        {
          name: 'check-box-3',
          key: 'checkBox3',
          label: 'Check Box 3',
          id: 'third',
          value: false
        },
        {
          name: 'check-box-4',
          key: 'checkBox4',
          label: 'Check Box 4',
          id: 'fourth',
          value: false
        },
      ];
```

My form is in a class component and I render it like this

```
class CheckIn extends Component {


state = {
    data1: ''
    
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
                                            {
        checkboxes && checkboxes 
        .map(checkbox => {
            return(
                <div className="checkbox-area" key={checkbox.id}>
                    <label htmlFor={ checkbox.id }>
                        <input type="checkbox" 
                        name="check-box" 
                        id={checkbox.id}  
                        value = {checkbox.value}
                        onChange = {this.handleCheck}
                        className='filled-in' />
                        <span>{checkbox.label}</span>
                    </label>
                 </div>
                 )
               })
                   }
                </div>

    )
}
}
```

I am not sure what to do in my handleCheck in order for the form to update state as true if it is checked and false it it is unchecked. For now, this only updates the checked ones and sends 'undefined'

```
    handleCheck = (e) => {
     this.setState({
         [e.target.id] : true
     })
    }
```

Please help. Thanks

Comment: Do you keep your checkboxes object in a state?

Comment: no, it is within the render function

Answer (score 1):

For `checkbox` type `input`, the value is `checked` not `value`.

This should work for you:

```html
<div className="checkbox-area" key={checkbox.id}>
    <label htmlFor={ checkbox.id }>
        <input type="checkbox" 
               name="check-box" 
               id={checkbox.id}  
               checked={checkbox.value}
               onChange={this.handleCheck}
               className='filled-in' />
        <span>{checkbox.label}</span>
    </label>
</div>
```

```js
handleCheck = e => {
  this.setState({
     [e.target.id]: e.target.checked
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfect for the ones that were checked. how would I set o state the ones that werent checked?

Comment: I'm not sure what's wrong with you code exactly, cause there is no snippet, but you can check this out: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-franklin-ziqrn?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark&file=/src/App.js, it's working example with a bit better aproach imho.

Comment: The code above is working well, just a little challenge, it only sets the checkbox on the state when a users clicks on the checkbox, how can I handle the checkboxes that are not clicked and set them as false? That is where I am stuck.

Comment: You have n checkboxes, if 3 are checked that means that n-3 are not. You can also pre-fill all of them with false value at beginning. I feel like you created the problem that doesn’t exist.

Comment: I know it is a little thing I just can't figure it out, sorry for the questions. of my n-checkboxes, I would like to add their id's to the state so that my state has the id's of both the unchecked and unchecked. the handleCheck function works on the changed ones. how can I create a function to handle the ones that arent changed?

Answer (score 0):

Based on your needed in your comment on @ulou answer post

You need to set all checkboxs state false first after component is mounted

```
class CheckIn extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        state = {
            data1: ''
        }
    }

    componentdidmount(){

    checkboxes.map(item => {
        this.setState({
            [item.id]: false
        })
    }

    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                { checkboxes && checkboxes 
                    .map(checkbox => {
                        return(
                            <div className="checkbox-area" key={checkbox.id}>
                                <label htmlFor={ checkbox.id }>
                                    <input type="checkbox" 
                                    name="check-box" 
                                    id={checkbox.id}  
                                    value = {checkbox.value}
                                    onChange = {this.handleCheck}
                                    className='filled-in' />
                                    <span>{checkbox.label}</span>
                                </label>
                            </div>
                        )
                    })
                }
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```